# ZipArchive numfiles inaccurate

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Zip archives `numFiles` seems to return 1 extra file than is actually contained in the archive. For example, if the archive only has 99 files, `numFiles` will say 100 files. In the following code `filesProcessed` is always +1 the actual amount of files (it was initialized as 0). Is this a known bug, or is the archive counting itself (the zip file) as a file?

```
public function zipExtract($file, $extractPath)
{
    if ($this->zip->open($file) === true) {
        $this->filesProcessed = $this->zip->numFiles;
        $this->zip->extractTo($extractPath);
        $this->zip->close();
    } else {
        throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__ . " could not extract file. Failed to open: {$file}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be Hidden files?

Comment: i cant confirm that, but on a test.zip with 3 files it correctly counts three. so im guessing somewhere in the file structure there must be a hidden file which is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, open any archive through WinRAR and see how many of the elements inside.
The screenshot shows that 4, but really 3 of them.

[image]

You need to do a check on the symbols **".."**

Comment: i dont think you are correct. if i zip 3 files i get 4 files, and if one of those files is in a directory you will get the same results. if you enter that directory you will also see '..' which is just the archives way of indicating the previous directory. this is also the case with recursive iterators as well.